# Let $n$ be a positive integer that has $6$ and $8$ as factors.

Tags: elementary-number-theory, discrete-mathematics

What other factors must $n$ have?

I don't understand if this means $n = 6k = 8k$ or $n = 6\times 8\times k$, also am not very sure about the specific factors and how they repeat.

Comment: It's that $n = 6k$ for some $k$ and then $n=6j$ for a *different* $j$.  You can't have $n = 6k = 8k$ because $6$ and $8$ aren't equal and $n$ doesn't have to be $0$.

Answer (score 2):

It means that there is an integer $k$ so that $n = 6k$ but "$k$" is not a magic number.  There is an integer $j$ (a *different* number) so that $n = 8j$ so $6k = 8j$.

Which means $3k = 4j$.  Which means $4$ must divide $k$ and so $4*6=24$ divides $6k$ and so $24$  must divide $n$.  And $3$ divides $j$ and so $3*8 = 24$ must divide $8j$ and so $24$ must divide $n$.

To formalize this if $w$ divides $n$ and $v$ also divides $n$ then the least common multiple of $w$ and $v$ must divide $n$.  The way to see this is to prime factorize: if $6|n$ then $6 = 2*3$ and $2$ and $3$ divide $n$.

As if $8|n$ then $8 =2^3$ so $2^3$ divides $n$.

So at least one power of $3$ divides $n$ and at least $3$ powers of $2$ divide $n$ so $3*2^3=24$ must divide $n$.

The trap *not* to fall for is if $8$ divides $n$ and $6$ divides $n$ then to think that $6*8=48$ divides $n$.  This doesn't have to be true because $6$ and $8$ have $2$ in common add when we multiply $6*8=48$ we are including that $2$ power two times when we only need to include it once.

This is why $\text{least common multiple}(w,v) =\frac {uv}{\text{greatest common divisor}(w,v)}$.

.......

So to recap and answer.  If we know $6$ divides $n$ and $8$ divides $n$ we know that the least common multiple of $6$ and $8$, that is $24$ must *also* divide $n$.

And therefore all divisors of the least common multiple $24$ divide $n$.

As $24 = 2^3*3^1$ so $1= 2^03^0$ and $2=2^13^0$ and $4=2^23^0$ and $8=2^33^0$ and $3=2^03^1$ and $6=2^13^1$ and $12=2^23^1$ and $24=2^33^1$ all *also* divide $n$.

Other numbers *might* divide $n$ but we don't know any of them for *certain*.

Comment: $1$ and $12$ also divide $n$

Comment: Oops.  Lost track of the question.  I was assuming it was obvious that all factors of factors are factors.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** Use the Fundamental Theorem of Arithmetic.

**Hint 2:** $6=2\times 3$ and $8=2\times 2\times 2$.

**Hint 3:** If $a\mid b$ and $b\mid n$, then $a\mid n$. (Why?)